# "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" After Windows Service Restart

Tags: c#, windows, ssl

I have a C# windows service that runs on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard with Service Pack 1.  When I reboot the server machine and start the windows service, it can successfully negotiate a secure connection with a third-party server, however, if I stop and restart the service, it begins to fail with the C# code exception of "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" and the Windows Event log shows "The following fatal alert was received: 48.", which according to this site:

```
 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2012/10/05/ssltls-alert-protocol-the-alert-codes/
```

indicates the certificate is not being completely validated, however, it works under a certain circumstance: if I reboot the server machine itself and start the windows service fresh, it starts working again.  If I stop the service and restart it again (without a server machine reboot), it stops working.

The C# 4.0 code adds a self-signed certificate from the third-party server it is accessing to a System.Net.HttpWebRequest to access the third-party server and the three third-party certificates are loaded into the server machine's Windows certificate store - the Root CA (.CER file), the Intermediate CA (.CER file) and the actual certificate (.PFX file) under the Windows account that runs the Windows service.

This has been happening on three different server machines for a year or more and I have looked on SO at a lot of the other various permeations of this error message, but they seem to be an all or nothing issue and not dependent on a sequence of reboots/restarts and mostly focus on changing code where, in my case, the code works under certain specific conditions.

Any ideas about what the initial run of the service is doing to prevent future service restarts from not working correctly?  I know there have been problems with various Windows Updates/Security patches for SSL, but it is not clear to me which of those may be causing this issue.

Comment: So the issue only occurs when you stop and start the service? when u start for first time all is ok? Could possibly be something to do with a connection not being closed or disposed properly and thus when it tries to connect a second time it fails as still old connection open maybe? I would start looking into your stop() method and disposing of everything in there

Comment: Yes, if I reboot the computer then start the service, it works, but when I then stop and restart the service, it stops working with the SSL connection error.  I do have code that closes the connection, however, the code making the SSL request is called on a frequent schedule by the Windows service, so even subsequent SSL requests work when the service is initially started from a reboot and that makes me think that it is not an issue speficially with the user code.